# Access VM Django Dev Server from Hyper-V VM Host Physical Machine

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-3.6, hyper-v

I am currently using Hyper-V to create a ubuntu 18.04.1 Desktop VM. On this VM I am creating a Django Dev Server using the following:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

When I go to the `0.0.0.0:8000` on the vm I am presented with the Django debug page. However, when I to the url on my desktop I `Unable to connect` screen.

When I run the server with an IP of anything other than 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1, I just `Error: That IP address cab't be assigned to.`

My Hyper-V Virtual Switch is an external network with my physical machines network adapter.

I am using Python 3.6.5, and Django 2.1

How do I access the Django Development Server on my VM hosts machine browser.

Comment: you have to access via the IP address of the virtual machine, which is different from your host and is not `0.0.0.0`, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thank you. seems link such a small thing